How to write a large vector to a file correctly?
I want to save a calculated vector of data to a file so I can load it later, avoiding the need to recalculate it every time the program starts.
The issue is that this works fine with relatively small datasets—for example, a vector with 1 million elements—but when I try using the full dataset of 32 million elements, the program gets stuck. I have to forcibly close it to get my saved file, but it then contains the correct amount of data (2.304 GB, since each element is 72 bytes). So, I don’t know why the program doesn’t continue and i have to forcibly close it to get my file. It just doesn’t reach the outFile.close();.
// Function to save a vector of DataArray to a binary file
void saveDataToFile(const std::vector<KlineDataArray>& data, const std::string& filePath) 
{
    std::ofstream outFile(filePath, std::ios::binary);
    if (!outFile.is_open()) 
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file for writing: " << filePath << '\n';
        return;
    }

    size_t dataSize{ data.size() };
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&dataSize), sizeof(size_t));
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data.data()), dataSize * sizeof(DataArray));
    outFile.close();
}


close isn't really needed since the first thing that happens after the close line is that outFile goes out of scope and calls close as part of its destruction.

Sidenote: size_t dataSize{ data.size() }; looks like a bad idea for a binary file. Use a fixed width type for the size, like uint32_t.

Attach a debugger to the program and break into the debugger after you've convinced yourself it is hanging? My money is on all those KlineDataArray destructors

@TedLyngmo oh thanks, I didn't think of that but the problem isnt really solved since it doesn't continue the debugging only goes until outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data.data()), dataSize * sizeof(KlineDataArray));  and then its stuck

Hmm, then perhaps run strace on the program to see what it's up to

could you be running out of memory ?

@AhmedAEK no the program only used around 1.5gb of RAM and I still had a lot left

Is it on a *nix or Windows system?

If you write the data in smaller chunks, how far does it get before stopping?

What type of filesystem is it writing to?

@TedLyngmo Im on windows so i sadly cant use strace and i havent quite found an alternative. Moreover its writing to a .bin file:
std::string saveFilePath{ saveFileDir + "accumulatedData_" + startDate + '_' + endDate + ".bin"};
saveDataToFile(accumulatedData, saveFilePath);

so I made smaller chunks and all of them work until the 12th file or 27528966 elements (I have a total of 13 files)

I just realized that 32 million times 72 bytes is a hair over 2 GB. Meanwhile, std::streamsize is a signed counterpart to size_t. If this code is compiled as 32 bits, datasize * sizeof(KlineDataArray) will overflow into a negative number.

@Botje Brilliant!

@Botje Damn, now it makes so much sense. I appreciate the help of you all!

The second argument to std::ostream::write is std::streamsize, which ...

is an implementation-defined signed integral type used to represent the number of characters transferred in an I/O operation or the size of an I/O buffer. It is used as a signed counterpart of std::size_t, similar to the POSIX type ssize_t.

On a 32-bit platform, that will be equivalent to a int32_t. And 32 million times 72 is just enough to overflow that into negative numbers...
I suggest you write in chunks of 720 MB or so, or forget that 32-bit exists and just compile as 64-bit.
